# use /opt/v8, instead of /usr in configure file

Tags: php, linux, laravel, v8, configure

I follow this guide: https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/master/README.Linux.md

I have a question:

> If you don't want to overwrite the system copy of v8, replace /usr in
>   the above commands with some other path like /opt/v8 and then add
>   --with-v8js=/opt/v8 to the php-v8js ./configure command below.

Where should I put --with-v8js=/opt/v8 in configure file?

Here is the configure file: http://expirebox.com/download/85d34ccf80cc75afc5fb41b3ae0ceec2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and then add --with-v8js=/opt/v8 to the php-v8js ./configure command`

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/phpv8/v8js.git
cd v8js
phpize
./configure --with-v8js=/opt/v8 <---this is where you add it
make
make test
sudo make install
```